# Creating a new table from existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to create a new table combining columns from multiple tables into one - simple enough. I wrote this query and when I went to retrieve some data there is NOTHING in the table but the column names. Am I missing a step?

```
Select E.PCR_ID as PreHospital_Report
    , E.eTimes_03 as DateofCall
    , R.eResponse_03 as IncidentID
    , R.eResponse_05 as TypeofService
    , GMR.dAgency_02 as GMR_AGENCY_NAME
    , S.eSituation_11 as Primary_Impression
    , S.eSituation_12 as Secondary_Impression
    , D.eDisposition_12 as Incident_Patient_Disposition
    , P.ePatient_15 as Age
    , P.ePatient_16 as Age_Units
    , V.EVitals_01 as Time_Vitals_Taken
    , V.EVitals_18 as Blood_Gluse_Level
    , V.eVitals_23 as Total_Glasgow_Coma_Scale
    , V.eVitals_26 as Level_of_Responsiveness
INTO GMR_FactTable_Call
FROM eTimes E
LEFT JOIN eResponse R ON E.PCR_ID = R.PCR_ID
LEFT JOIN ePatient P ON E.PCR_ID = P.PCR_ID
LEFT JOIN eVitals V ON E.PCR_ID = V.PCR_ID
LEFT JOIN eSituation S ON E.PCR_ID = S.PCR_ID
LEFT JOIN dAgency GMR ON E.PCR_ID = GMR.PCR_ID
LEFT JOIN eDisposition D ON E.PCR_ID = D.PCR_ID
WHERE E.eTimes_03 >= '01/01/2019'
```

Comment: remove the `Into GMR_FactTable_Call` first and execute the query, make sure the query is correct and return the result that you wanted

Comment: @Squirrel Yes i did that at first but the fact all the source data is VARCHAR is causing date issues that I need to correct. thanks for the advice as I tried to find a SQL tutor to pay but really could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `WHERE` clause may not be behaving as you expect.  Change this:

```sql
WHERE E.eTimes_03 >= '01/01/2019'
```

to this:

```sql
WHERE E.eTimes_03 >= '20190101'
```

If this fixes the problem, then it means that your current `WHERE` clause isn't matching any data.  This borders on being a typo, but it's important to always remember to use proper date literals in your query.  The corrected version above uses an unambiguous format which should work regardless of your server settings.

Comment: Thank you Tim- this helped me alot and worked

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have data for condition `E.eTimes_03 >= '01/01/2019'`

Also, always ensure that you are having datetime defined properly as per your language settings.see what is your language settings. Is the dateformat set as `dmy` or `mdy` ?

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

You will get response as given below:

| Set Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| textsize | 2147483647 |
| language | us_english |
| **dateformat** | **mdy** |
| ... | ... |

Now, you need to define your datetime value accordingly.

```sql
E.eTimes_03 >= '18/12/2019' -- dmy

E.eTimes_03 >= '12/18/2019' -- mdy
```

Or you can go for ISO8601 format, which is agnostic of language settings.

```sql
E.eTimes_03 >= '2019-12-18' -- YYYY-MM-DD format
```

Comment: @DaleK, sorry. will take care in future. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @DaleK, got it. I have removed image and updated my answer